# How to set up Azure Sync to other databases to delete records that are no longer in the source

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I'm very new to Azure so please don't judge me too harshly.

So, in this project, I've got SQL Server on-premises 'production' database which is the 'master' data. I'm writing a small .NET application that is published on Azure and it is using tables and stored procedures on Azure database. My idea is to have the data in the tables on Azure database up-to-date with the on-premises 'production' database tables.

I've created Sync Group and Sync Agent and it looks like data is flowing accurately from the on-premises Sql Server tables to Azure database tables.

The only problem I have is that when some records on 'prodution' are **deleted** these records will **not** be deleted from the Azure tables.

I guess the questions are: What am I missing in synchronization and is it even the right approach to update the Azure database tables using the 'Sync to other databases' tool?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have elected the Azure SQL Database as the Hub in your sync group and the on-premise as a member database.

For the Conflict Resolution Policy of the Sync Group, make sure you have selected "Member wins".

Comment: That's exactly how I set it up. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According your problem description, since your Azure SQL Data Sync group has be created, we can get that:

1. Your on-premise SQL server DB is member database.
2. The Azure SQL database is Hub database.
3. The Sync Direction of your Sync must be "*Member to Hub*" or "Bi-directional Sync",

> The only problem I have is that when some records on 'production' are deleted these records will not be deleted from the Azure tables.

For your question, I don't think Conflict Resolution Policy can help you solve it.
[image]

There isn't a good solution now, I only can give two suggestions for you:

1. Set **Automatic Sync: Off**. Sync the data from on-premises SQL
   server to Azure manually. This can help your keep
   the data in Azure SQL DB for a long time.
2. Create a new table in Azure SQL database, don't add the new table to
   sync group. Copy the data from your synced table to new table. Using the new
   table for test.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, and you guessed set-up right, it's Member to Hub. The idea is to have the process run automatically, I don't want to run the sync manually every 30 mins.

Comment: yes, @landrew sync manually is very hard for you. According my experience,  Data Sync can not achieve it for now.If my answer is helpful for you, please accept(mark) it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: I think I haven't got a helpful answer yet.